# Pip install fails on l18n. Setuptools issue due to corrupted python install?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, virtualenv, wagtail

My server ran out of space and it seems to have corrupted the python virtual environments for my Django/Wagtail sites. Initially loading the virtual environment pip could not be found. Then creating a new environment and running pip install -r requirements/production.txt fails on l18n with this:

```
Collecting l18n>=2018.5 (from wagtail==2.16.2->-r requirements/base.txt (line 74))
  Using cached l18n-2020.6.1-py3-none-any.whl (51 kB)
  Using cached l18n-2020.6.tar.gz (50 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [13 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/tmp/pip-install-4mnshni5/l18n_23c98b9215ae4661b446bfc6d5a98ee8/setup.py", line 74, in <module>
          cmd_module = getattr(__import__('setuptools.command', fromlist=[cmd]),
      AttributeError: module 'setuptools.command' has no attribute 'bdist_wininst'
      
      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
      
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-4mnshni5/l18n_23c98b9215ae4661b446bfc6d5a98ee8/setup.py", line 78, in <module>
          cmd_module = getattr(__import__('distutils.command', fromlist=[cmd]),
      AttributeError: module 'distutils.command' has no attribute 'bdist_wininst'
      [end of output]
```

Installing l18n on its own seems to work but since its installed as a Wagtail dependency and failing on that I am not sure how to resolve it.

pip install l18n
Requirement already satisfied: l18n in /var/www/envs/metavision_3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (2021.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in /var/www/envs/metavision_3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from l18n) (2023.3.post1)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /var/www/envs/metavision_3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from l18n) (1.16.0)

pip install -r requirements/production.txt

That it would succeed in installing listed packages and their dependencies, rather than failing with the above error.